# How to implement Firebase Google Auth in an ElectronJs App that runs in background?

Tags: macos, firebase-authentication, electron, electron-forge

I am building an ElectronJs application which runs in background (in tray). I want to add `Sign in with Google` feature in the app using Firebase Auth. I tried searching but do not see any documentation around it. Few issues I faced:

- I could get it working with the Renderer process but I want my Main process to hold `User` object as main process does API calls in background that require Auth token.
- My app runs in background in tray, so it does not have an active window open at any time.

Is there a way I can implement auth code in main process and then use IPC to open the login window using renderer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me

1. Redirect user to a browser to login page. When login is done, trigger a deep link that opens the app. The deep link should contain the idToken other params.
2. Parse the token from the url and use `signinwithcredentials` API of firebase auth. This takes the credentials object and performs the login.